# How to add class to previous iteration when current Iteration is true in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop

I'm facing some issue in adding class to previous iteration when current iteration is true can someone help me in this?

So I'm drawing the Box, and adding class to Box. If some condition is true, But Now I want if condition is true for current loop, add class to previous box. Here is the code

```
 const addClass=(isTrue)=>{debugger
    let name=""
    if(isTrue){
       name="setLine"
    }
    return name
  }

const getValue = (item, depotName) => {
    let count = "";
    for(let i=0;i<item?.length;i++){
       if(item[i].from===depotName&&item[i-1].to===depotName){
        count=item[i].qty+item[i-1].qty;
      
       }
    }
    return count;
  };


 {item?.depots?.distribution?.map((depot, index) => (
                   
                      <div className={`multi-spply-container ${addClass( getValue(item, depot.depotName)}`} key={index}>
                      <Box/>))}
```

So now what happening is suppose there is 3 box, and 2nd box and  3rd box is true(this is the condition) only for that box class is adding("setLine"). But what I want is as 2nd box is true I want to add class to 1st Box also . Suppose 3rd box is true I want to add class to 1st and 2nd So on.Can Someone help me on this please?

Comment: what is `isTransfer`?

Comment: isTransfer is variable it's gives true or false to the Box, And isTransfer is handling based on some value in another function.

Comment: Create a snippet or codesandbox to demo this.

Comment: from where you get the `isTransfer` variable ? is it inside the distribution array ?

Comment: No it's not there in array , It's handled in another function , In that function It's returning true or false. Here I just mentioned isTransfer

Comment: @sss If there are 10 boxes and only 5th box is true, then box 1 to 5 should be true and  6 to 10 will be false or no class ? Is this the behaviour you want ?

Comment: Yes, I want it like that @PR7

Comment: @sss can you please provide the code where you are setting the value of isTransfer please ?

Comment: Ok I will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve this. Before rendering, find the index of the last box that is true. While rendering check if the current index is less than or equal to the last true index then add class `setLine`.

```
const addClass = (isTrue) => {
  debugger
  let name = ""
  if (isTrue) {
    name = "setLine"
  }
  return name
}

const getValue = (item, depotName) => {
  let count = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < item ? .length; i++) {
    if (item[i].from === depotName && item[i - 1].to === depotName) {
      count = item[i].qty + item[i - 1].qty;
    }
  }
  return count;
};

// Find last index which is true
let lastTrueIndex = -1;
item?.depots?.distribution?.forEach((depot, index) => {
  if (getValue(item, depot.depotName)) {
    lastTrueIndex = index;
  }
});


// If the index of the box in the iteration is less than or equal to
// last true index then add class setLine.
{
  item?.depots?.distribution?.map((depot, index) => (
  <div className = {
    `multi-spply-container ${index <= lastTrueIndex ? "setLine" : ""}`
  }
  key = {index} />
  <Box / > ))
}
```